# How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

I added a tag to the master branch on my machine:

```
git tag mytag master
```

How do I push this to the remote repository? Running `git push` gives the message:

> Everything up-to-date

However, the remote repository does not contain my tag.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

To push specific, one tag do following
`git push origin tag_name`

Answer (score 5618):

To push a **single** tag:

```
git push origin <tag_name>
```

And the following command should push **all** tags (**not recommended**):

```
# not recommended
git push --tags
```

Comment: I recommend not using or training others to use `git push --tags` as it can be very very difficult to get rid of bad tags when your co-workers are trained to push all tags, as people continue to push the old bad tags they have locally every time they want to push a new tag. Because of this, I will only every advise someone to use `git push origin <tag_name>` now.

Comment: To push a **moved** tag:  `git push origin <tag_name> --force`

Comment: If your tag is the same as remote branch and `git push` fails with `error: src refspec <tag_name> matches more than one.`, you can push it as `git push origin tag <tag_name>`

Comment: Note that `git push --tags origin <tag_name>` **IS NOT** what you want - despite naming a specific tag, it pushes them all, even lightweight ones. Sigh.

Comment: If you want to push all tags, you could first `git push --dry-run --tags origin` to see what will get pushed.

Comment: `git push origin <tag_name>` not worked for me. `git push origin refs/tags/<tag_name>`works.

Comment: I know that I can push multiple tags with one command ( `git push origin tag1 tag2 tag3` ) but is there a way to push tags with a wildcard (e.g. only release tags)?  I tried `git push origin 'Release_*'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1561):

**`git push --follow-tags`**

This is a sane option introduced in Git 1.8.3:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

It pushes both commits and only tags that are both:

- annotated
- reachable (an ancestor) from the pushed commits

This is sane because:

- you should only push annotated tags to the remote, and keep lightweight tags for local development to avoid tag clashes. See also: [What is the difference between an annotated and unannotated tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514075)
- it won't push annotated tags on unrelated branches

It is for those reasons that `--tags` should be avoided.

Git 2.4 [has added](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61ca378275e83c48343c74a849ff0dcdef9abc91) the `push.followTags` option to turn that flag on by default which you can set with:

```
git config --global push.followTags true
```

or by adding `followTags = true` to the `[push]` section of your `~/.gitconfig` file.

#### Visual Studio Code

To activate this in Visual Studio Code set the variable `"git.followTagsWhenSync": true` on a user or workspace basis. [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103281)

Comment: It was not clear at once for me that it was an and-relation between "annotated" and "reachable from the pushed commits". I hoped it would push all reachable tags, whatever if annotated or not. Maybe edit to make sure it's not an OR?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in git 2.5.0, but `git push origin --tags` does.

Comment: @nnyby please provide a minimal example with all necessary commands from repo creation to failure and post it on a gist so I can try to reproduce ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the push.followTags tip.  I can't believe this isn't the out-of-the-box default.  Without it, don't even bother to tag, you'll forget and get out of sync tags.

Comment: Added a line about setting the follow-tags through the config file.

Answer (score 126):

To expand on [Trevor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195913/456814), you can push a single tag or all of your
tags at once.

### Push a Single Tag

```
git push <remote> <tag>
```

This is a summary of the [relevant documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) that explains this (some
command options omitted for brevity):

> ```
> git push [[<repository> [<refspec>…]]
>
> <refspec>...
> ```
>
> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is…the source ref `<src>`,
>   followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`…
>
> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this
>   push…If `:<dst>` is omitted, the same ref as `<src>` will be
>   updated…
>
> tag `<tag>` means the same as `refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>`.

### Push All of Your Tags at Once

```bash
git push --tags <remote>
# Or
git push <remote> --tags
```

Here is a summary of the [relevant documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) (some command options
omitted for brevity):

> ```
> git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
>
> --tags
> ```
>
> All refs under `refs/tags` are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly
>   listed on the command line.

Comment: The example is leaving out the keyword `tag`.  e.g. `git push origin tag funny-tag-1`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 You don't need it. You push a single tag to origin like this: `git push origin my-tag` (I just tried it!)

Comment: I was using version *1.9.1*, what about you @AndresF. ?

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 Version `2.10.2`. Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 113):

Add a tag in your current branch. If you want to create the tag for your master, first check out to master.

```
git tag tag_name
```

Check if it's created or not

```
git tag
```

Push in your remote origin

```
git push origin tag_name
```

Answer (score 89):

You can push all local tags by simply `git push --tags` command.

```
$ git tag                         # see tag lists
$ git push origin <tag-name>      # push a single tag
$ git push --tags                 # push all local tags
```

Answer (score 69):

Tags are not sent to the remote repository by the git push command. We need to explicitly send these tags to the remote server by using the following command:

```
git push origin <tagname>
```

We can push all the tags at once by using the below command:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Here are some resources for complete details on git tagging:

http://www.cubearticle.com/articles/more/git/git-tag

http://wptheming.com/2011/04/add-remove-github-tags

Answer (score 55):

You can push the tags like this `git push --tags`

Comment: Very unrecommended

Answer (score 27):

> How can I push my tag to the remote repository so that all client computers can see it?

Run this to push `mytag` to your git origin (eg: GitHub or GitLab)

```
git push origin refs/tags/mytag
```

It's better to use the full "refspec" as shown above (literally `refs/tags/mytag`) just in-case `mytag` is actually `v1.0.0` and is ambiguous (eg: because there's a branch also named `v1.0.0`).

Answer (score 22):

I am using `git push <remote-name> tag <tag-name>` to ensure that I am pushing a tag.  I use it like: `git push origin tag v1.0.1`.  This pattern is based upon the documentation (`man git-push`):

```
OPTIONS
   ...
   <refspec>...
       ...
       tag <tag> means the same as refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>.
```

Answer (score 8):

### push tag to remote

```bash
git push origin mytag
```

### fetch all tags from remote

```bash
git fetch --all --tags
```

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this :

```
git push --tags origin <branch-name> <tag-name>

e.g. : git push --tags origin master v2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am using Git version `2.30.0` I tried both `--follow-tags` and `--tags`, but both of them didn't work to push all the tags to the remote repo. I ended up using:

```
+refs/remotes/origin/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

So for those who are looking for a way to **push all the tags (along with master) to a remote repo**, you can just add the following `+refs/remotes/origin/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to your `push` command.

So your command should be something like this:

```
git push path/to/your/repo +refs/remotes/origin/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

It will successfully create all your tags in the remote repo.

Comment: Why overcomplicate life mate

Comment: @Mehdi how is that? It's just the command I used in my case when we are unable to push tags to a remote, in my cas that was the unique way to do it.

Comment: That was not the question though

Comment: Yes, maybe but it's worthy posting it, as I said **it's for for those who struggle to push *all their tags to a remote***. It might be helpful for someone else.