# git: push only specific tags

Tags: git, tags

AFAIK, `git push --tag` pushes every tags under refs/tags to remote. I want to know if there is a way in git to only push some tags that matches a wildcard or regexp?

For example, my repo has tag `v1.0`, `v1.1`, `v2.0` and `v2.1`. I want to only push `v2.*`. I tried

```
git push <repo> refs/tags/v2.*
```

and got error

> fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in refs/tags/v2.*

Of course, I can always do

```
cd .git && ls refs/tags/v2.* | xargs git push <repo>
```

But this does not smell gity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
git tag | grep '^v2\.' | xargs --no-run-if-empty  git push <repo>
```

- `.git` may not be directory, it may not be there at all. Submodules have there file pointing to root repository. Or you can have `GIT_DIR` set to somewhere else.
- When no tags match your criteria, you do not want to do the push.

Comment: What if there is a local branch named "v2.0"? How is `git push` resolve ambiguous names?

Comment: It is bad idea to have tags and branches of the same name. Git does not hande this well. Use `v2.0` for tags and something like `stable-2.x` for branches. Example: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=summary

Comment: See [`gitrevisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) ("When ambiguous, a <name> is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules").

Comment: So tag always takes priority than branches. That's good to know. Josef, could you please add this information to your answer and I will mark complete. Thanks!

Comment: `git tag | grep '^v2\.'` can be simplified to `git tag -l "v2\.*"`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438076/2726840)  is relevant: `git push --follow-tags` do push all tags reachable from the current branch and are from annotated type tag. (git >= 1.8.3). This can be set as option to git config also for git versions greater than 2.4

Answer (score 21):

```
git push <remote> tag <tag>
```

In your case it will be

```
git push origin tag v2.*
```

Comment: I like this Simple solution better.

Comment: but it doesn't work