# How to merge specific commits from master to tag in git?

Tags: git, merge

I want to merge some commits from master to a tag.

We create tags to mark major releases. However, if we need to do some quick fixes. We do it in master. But then we need to merge those commits to the tag.

In addition, not all commits needs to be merged at times. That's why we need to choose specific commits only..

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `git-cherry-pick` command ([doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html))

```
git checkout <TAG_NAME>
git cherry-pick <COMMIT_HASH>
```

Or you can even apply the most recent commit from the master `git cherry-pick master`

Comment: i see. thanks! another thing. i mentioned i created tags. now, i realized it's just on my local. how do i actually create tags on remote from a specific commit?

Comment: Here you can find the answer how to push tag to remote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-can-i-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git