# Why cant i see my git tag on the bitbucket remote repository?

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket

I have tried to tag by release from my ide (Intellij) , its seems to have worked in that there were no errors and if I run

```
git tag
```

from the command line my tag is listed

But I cant see the tag from the BitBucket master repository that I cloned from 
and when I try to push my repository it says there is nothing to push

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)

Comment: Jubobs thanks it is a duplicate in that the solution of doing git push --tags works, but its not a duplicate in the sense that that answer does not explain why Intellij says everything is update to date instead of pushing the tag.

Comment: IntelliJ (Git, really) won't tell you that you have yet to push a tag. Only the relative position of the current branch and the corresponding remote-tracking branch (if any) determines whether you're up to date or not.

Comment: @Jubobs I dont get it IntelliJ knows when I have code to push why it cant do the same with tags, but then my understanding of git is rather limited