# fatal error when pushing TAG to server

Tags: git, tfs

I have TFS GIT where my code base has been uploaded. I come from a TFS background where I am used to creating labels to create a snapshot of my code at any point in time. For TFS GIT, I found out that I need to create tags. However these tags only get created locally on my dev box.I want this tag to be pushed to the central repository but when I run this command on the command prompt:

```
git push origin MyTag
```

I get this error

```
fatal: MyTag cannot be resolved to branch.
Unexpected end of command stream
```

As far as I know, I am on the main branch, or the branch that gets created by default when you upload your code. I have not created any specific branches as such. How does one push a TAG from one dev box to the TFS server and then get it on another developer's box? I dont think creating a branch for every intended snapshot/label is a good idea.

Thoughts??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)

Comment: No its not a duplicate. That question was how to push a tag. I have tried the same command as explained there and got an error. I think I am passing the correct command as shown on that accepted answer. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

When just asking for `git push origin MyTag`, git expects a *branch* name to be pushed and not a *tag* name (as it tells you in the error message).

In order to push a certain **tag**, you need to specify the exact tag name:

```
git push origin refs/tags/MyTag
```

or

```
git push origin tag MyTag
```

From [`man git-push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> The object referenced by `<src>` is used to update the `<dst>` reference on the remote side. **By default this is only allowed if `<dst>` is not a tag** (annotated or lightweight), and then only if it can fast-forward `<dst>`.
>   ...
>   `tag <tag>` means the same as `refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>`.

If you want to push *all* your tags to `origin`, do

```
git push origin --tags
```