# git push and fetch annotated tag does not create the tag

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag, git-fetch

I just created an annotated tag on machine A, then pushed the tag to the server S:

```
@A$ git tag -a v1 -m"Release version 1"
@A$ git push origin_on_S v1
```

Then on machine B, I tried to fetch the tag:

```
@B$ git fetch origin v1
```

I got the commit, but not the tag. The reply from `fetch` was:

```
From <server_S/repo>
 * tag               v1 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Then nothing. `FETCH_HEAD` was updated, but apparently no annotated tag was created.

I am currently trying `git fetch origin v1:v1`, but I had the impression that `git fetch tag` should fetch both the data and the annotated tag. Was I wrong, or did I do something wrong to prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)

Comment: @Jububs - I think his push is actually OK, and it is the fetch that is the problem here.  Not sure if you can fetch a single tag to something other than FETCH_HEAD.

Comment: @jububs : @Andrew C is correct. I could finally get the fetch to work, with the `:`, but I'm not sure. I need to build a simple test case to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it like

```
git push --tags
```

Comment: But that would push all my tags, annotated or not.