# GIT-Unable to push to remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, git-push

I have a shell script running on a Jenkins box in which I am cloning my repository via HTTP and trying to push some changes also via HTTP to a remote branch which already exists.

However I keep getting *failed to push refs* error and adding `--verbose` doesn't really tell me why the error is happening. I don't believe it is a user permission issue since the user I used to clone the repository has master permission in our internal gitlab repo.

```
+ git status
On branch npm_publish
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/npm_publish' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

//Grepping the remote branches to make sure npm_publish is there
+ grep npm_publish
+ git branch -a
* npm_publish
  remotes/origin/npm_publish
+ git pull
Already up-to-date.
+ git push -u origin npm_publish --verbose
Pushing to https://<username>:<password>!@<internal repository>/quality/test.git
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<username>:<password>!@<internal repository>/quality/test.git'
```

UPDATE:
so before this step I do an

```
npm install
npm install grunt-cli
```

before pushing if I do

```
rm -r node_modules
```

it pushes just fine. Why would installing npm modules

Comment: Could you try to update your repo from the remote using `git pull`before to push. It seems your repo is not up tp date

Comment: @Flows It didn't do any difference. I updated my question with the git pull statement output

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is similar kind of issue which you are facing. See if could fit your need.

[Push a tag to a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git?rq=1)

Regards.