# When must the tag be set for github push?

Tags: git, github, tagging

I don't understand how to tag a version properly in git so the version is pushed to github together with the tag.

In fact I don't even know which is the right moment for setting the the tag name.

Do I need to set the tag before the local commit or after the local commit?

I've seriously checked the git documentation.

And then, when I want to push to remote i.e. github do I explicitly need to set the tag name again like in this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195913/716568

Is there no way to automatically push in sync with the currently set local tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right moment for setting tag name is when you create the tag. And you can create and push it at any time. You can create a tag immediately after commit or a week later. Up to you.

When you want to push tag(s) with commits either you name the tags in the command line (`git push origin master tag v3.42`, for example) or you can add push.followTags=true to config: `git config [--global] push.followTags true` (`[--global]` means optional — you have to decide if you want the settings in your global config (per-user) file or local (per repo)); with this setting git pushes tags when it pushes commits pointed to by these tags.

You may push a tag alone: `git push origin tag v3.42`. Git will push the tag and all commits required to complete the branch.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation and clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I found two ways to do this.

1.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "a msg"
$ git push origin master tag v1.0.0
```

2.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "msg"
$ git tag v1.0.1
$ git push origin master --tags
```

You can add a message to a tag like this:

```
$ git tag v2.0.0 -m "second release"
$ git push origin master tag v2.0.0
```

But as far as I can tell the only way to have a tag show as the latest release is to add a title to it on github.com

You can find more info with `$ git help tag` and `$ git help push`