# Push tags with Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, git, git-push, git-tag, xcode9-beta

From cli I push tags like this

```
git tag 1.0.1 && git push origin 1.0.1
```

From Xcode 9 I can tag commits. But, how do I push that tag to origin from Xcode?

Comment: Also I need to know how to; I have tried to commit/push after create a tag, but in remote repository I don't see the tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w) (released 2018-06-04, coincident with WWDC18), we can now optionally push tags to the remote during normal push actions. (**Source Control -> Push...**) There does not, however, appear to be a mechanism to selectively push tags.

[image: Xcode 10 Tag Pushing]

---

### Historical Info

As of Xcode 9.1 (9B55), this is currently impossible. I'm certain it will be fixed in an update (though it doesn't exist in Xcode 9.2b2).

As an aside, if you have made several tags and want to push all of them to the remote from the command-line, you can do `git push origin --tags`.

**Update 2018-04:** pushing tags still unimplemented as of Xcode 9.3 (9E145)

**Update 2018-05:** unimplemented as of Xcode 9.4 (9F1027a)

To my further surprise, setting `git config --global push.followTags true`, which causes all reachable and annotated tags to be pushed when performing `git push`, has no effect from within Xcode. ([Info on push.followTags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438076/4095935))

**Update 2018-06:** The release notes for today's Xcode 10 beta include this quite satisfying entry:

> Tags can optionally be pushed from the push sheet. (40141815)

I'm downloading it now and will confirm once it is installed.

Comment: 'git push origin --tags' from the command line did push the tag.  I also cannot figure out how to make Xcode push the tag (as of Xcode v9.2), not sure this answer really answers the question, which was how to push it from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Tag name should start with an alphabet. For example, v1.0.1. Then it will reflect in the remote repository.