# Can see my tag in my local .git repository but not on github

Tags: git, github

I have this scenario :

I Can see my tag in my local .git repository when typing this command:

```
git ls-remote --tags origin | grep 12.55.8.21
701d54524eb7bec2eeed9da8a849563a84f6f277        refs/tags/12.55.8.21
01e55129b7621f2dbea7975a6fa9da6d6e38e203        refs/tags/12.55.8.21^{}
```

but when going to GitHub I can not find this tag nor the commit attached to it (701d54524eb7bec2eeed9da8a849563a84f6f277)

[image]

What am I missing?

Because I know that "git ls-remote" shows me remote branches.

Comment: did you [`git push --tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195859)?

Comment: no. But I don't want them to be on the remote I just don't understand how I can see them in different servers if they are not in GitHub

Comment: What "different servers"? Is your `origin` pointing to GitHub or somewhere else?

Comment: by writing "different servers" I meant, that I cloned the repository into 2 different local machines. Which there I can see the tags when using this command: "git ls-remote --tags origin | grep 12.55.8.21"