# "git push --force --follow-tags" is not pushing tags when using force

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

I erased a tag locally and remotely, edited some commits, made a new local tag, and I wanted to push everything all at once, so I tried

```sh
git push --force --follow-tags
```

but it seems that when I use the `--force` option, it does not push tags of the new commits that I'm force pushing.

Why not? How do we do it in one transaction like `git push --follow-tags`, but also with `--force`?

Comment: why not git push --force --tags ?

Comment: @battlmonstr Because it would do something different?

Comment: @battlmonstr Does `git push --force --tags` push my branch, plus any tags? Or just tags?

Comment: `--tags` pushes only tags, but all of them. `--follow-tags` works very differently from that.

Comment: Right. If you have just 1 tag then `git push origin <tag_name> --force` seems possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git . Otherwise probably need 2 commands.

Comment: @battlmonstr What if my tag is not at HEAD of my branch? I want to push everything in my branch, and the tag(s) (I don't care if I push all of them outside of my branch though), in one single transaction, just like `--follow-tags` normally works without `--force`.