# how to move a tag on a git repository

Tags: git

I am trying to switch a CI system from using a deploy branch to using a deploy tag.

When I go to gitlab, pick a commit and tag it, it's all good and the tag is available in the repository.

When I add a tag on my system:

```
git tag -f deploy master
```

I get a local tag but then I need to push it.

I read this page: [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)

but it left me confused since it talks about local tags, but also that pushing tags and tags that were moved seems to be different.

so my question is: how can I move the *deploy* tag, both locally and on the remote server, to the head, using the command line?

Comment: What happened after you did `git push origin <tagname>`, as noted in the other question?

Comment: I get: error: src refspec deploy does not match any

Comment: That error (`src refspec deploy does not match any`) means you *don't* have a `deploy` branch or tag.

Comment: right; I had one, and I removed it during testing; I need to find a solution where: if it is not there, it's created at the head, if it's there, it's moved to the head and where I have both a remote and a local identical tag.