# How do I push the last created tag to remote

Tags: git, npm, version-control

I understand that you push a tag by running:

`git push origin v0.1.0`

Where v0.1.0 is the name of the tag I created. I am looking for a command that just pushes the last tag I created, without needing to specify the number/name of the tag.

Comment: You can push all tags: `git push origin --tags`. This does what you want if the tag you just made is the only tag not on remote

Comment: wouldn't that push all of the tags? I just want the latest

Comment: Assuming your local tags are the same as the remote, then pushing them causes no harm. But in general pushing all tags is not the best of ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a `tag` at the HEAD, you'll do something like:

```
git tag <tagName>
```

If you use bash, on the very next terminal command you can do:

```
git push origin !$
```

`!$` referes to the last word of the last command, which in this case will be your `<tagName>`.

In general, you can get the list of sorted tags like this:

```
git tag --sort=creatordate
```

Using that, you can push your last tag like this:

```
git push origin $(git tag --sort=creatordate | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: this works great. Thanks!!


`git push origin $(git tag --sort=creatordate | tail -n 1)`

Comment: Awesome. Don't forge to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers