# Jenkins, get code from Git by tag and not branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I trying to get code from git in Jenkins pipeline by tag without success.
with the following code:

- git branch: 'tag name', credentialsId: 'my credentials', url: 'my url'

I get following error:

- ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job. Finished: FAILURE

I tried the following as well:

- git branch: 'tags/tag name', credentialsId: 'my credentials', url: 'my url'

same issue

Comment: Have you actually pushed the tag?

Comment: what you meant?

Comment: Tags are not pushed by default, so it might be the case that the tag exists only in your local repository, but not on remote. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195859/7571258

Answer (score 0):

Try git branch: '*/tags/tag name'