# How to associate a commit to a tag or vice-versa

Tags: git

I have several commits, but once I release I'd like to associate a tag to it.

I know the relevant commands are `commit`, `tag` and `push`.

In which order should I do it - so that the last or the one I'm about to do is associated with the tag I'm about to push?

Would it be `git commit`, then `git tag` and then `git push`?

Comment: If you don't commit before tagging, you'll tag the *previous* commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the right order - you first need to create a commit (`git commit`). Then tag it and give it a meaningful name (`git tag`). Once you've did that, push the commit and its tag to the remote repo (`git push`).

Answer (score 0):

First:

1. commit all you need with `git add . && git commit -m "commit message"`

Then:

2. If you have several commits and you want to tag it all together:

   2.1. `git rebase  -i HEAD~<X>`, where **X** is the number of commits
3. Tagging: `git tag <tag-name>`, where **tag-name** is the tag you want
4. If you have your commit pushed

   4.1. `git push --follow-tags`, as a good way to push your tag, as you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)
5. If not, you can push just one tag:

   5.1. `git push origin <tag_name>`