# Forgot to add tag to git push

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

I made a push from a local repository to a remote one, but now realize I needed to have a tag on it. Is there a way to add a tag after the push?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-tag%5D+after+push

Answer (score 3):

You can add a tag at any time. Just add the commit hash to the tag command. For example

```sh
git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02
```

(example taken from the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), section "Tagging Later")

Then push your tags

```sh
git push --tags
```

Comment: I would advise to use `git push origin <tag_name>`

Comment: @Eneko What should this advice be good for? `origin` is the default remote anyway. See [doc for git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). So, why would you advise to push to `origin` if another remote can be configured?

Comment: Mostly to avoid pushing local tags to upstream.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `origin` _is_ the default upstream. So, unless you have defined a different remote you are pushing to `origin` anyway, whether you name that upstream explicitely or use the default.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am not being able to explain properly. The original comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git#comment40809114_5195913

Comment: Ah, got it finally ;-) your point is to recommend pushing a single tag instead of pushing all tags. Since that requires a refspec for the tag and one cannot provide a refspec without providing a repository, the repository must be given too (which can be the name of a remote). So, it is not about providing `origin` or not. The advice is to push a single tag instead of using `--all`. That's a valid point, but it would have been helpful to express that intent explicitly (or link to the reference right away). My intent was to push all tags ;-)