# how to tag triggered pipeline with triggering pipeline info on azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

i have release pipelines which gets triggered on pipeline resources but would like to have  release pipeline gets tagged with triggering pipeline(build) info, so we can have filter about what  deployed on when.

I am trying to tag release pipeline with apiname variable using logging command, but i am unable to see them or filter with them .

below is the my release pipeline code

```
 resources:
 pipelines:
 - pipeline: pipeline1
   project: appcom
   source: pipeline-api
   trigger:
     branches:
     - develop
     - feat/*
-  pipeline: pipeline2
   project: appcom
   source: pipeline2-api
   trigger:
     branches:
     - develop
     - feat/*

 variables:
 - name: alias
   value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)

 stages:
 - stage: ScanImage
   jobs:
   - job: ScanImage
     pool:
       vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
     steps:
     - script: echo $(alias)

     - task: Bash@3
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable 
             variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)"
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable 
             variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceCommit) 
             | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline1-api"
          elif [ "$(alias)" = "pipeline2" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable 
            variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.pipelineName)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable 
            variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceCommit) 
            | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline2-api"
          fi

     - script: echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)"
```

release pipeline runs:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

it does not show any tags while filtering and it simply says no tags

below is the screenshot of bash script which set tag
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

but unable to filter is using this tag.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVjGS.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaXJJ.png

Comment: Can you share the build results to see failed steps?

Comment: but my requirement here is i need to tag this release pipeline with apiname..  in above code you could apiname is set as variable with predefined variable.. is it possible to tag with apiname ???

Comment: @pranathi. Of course. You can do it. Since you have set the apiname as variable, you can directly use it in the Rest API URL with the the format $(apiname). Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to tag with apiname variable in above pipeline?

From your yaml sample, you have set the apiname variable in PowerShell task.

So you could directly use the variable in the next task with the format `$(apiname)`

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organizationname}/{projectname}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/tags/$(apiname)?api-version=6.0
```

Here is an example:

```
steps:
     - script: echo $(alias)

     - task: Bash@3
        ....

     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           $token = "PAT"
           
           $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organizationname}/{projectname}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/tags/$(apiname)?api-version=6.0"
           
           $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
           
           
           $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Put  -ContentType application/json
```

Here is a doc about [the Tags - Add Build Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/add%20build%20tag?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [create PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

**Note** The PAT Token need to has the scope `vso.build_execute`
[image]

**Update:**

To use Bash script to run the Rest API:

```
curl -X POST \
-u :{PAT}  https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/tags?api-version=6.0 \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d ' ["$(apiname)"]'
```

**Update2:**

```
curl -X POST \
-u :$(System.AccessToken)  https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/tags?api-version=6.0 \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d ' ["$(apiname)"]'
```

**Note**: you need to select the option: **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** in Agent Job.

[image]

If it reports the error about having no permission, you need to grant the **Manage build queue** permission for the **projectname build service (organizationname)** account

[image]

**Update3:**

You can aslo use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build) to set the build tag:

Here is the bash script:

```
echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)"
```

Comment: shall i use same in bash script, as i will have issues with powershell script on my agents

Comment: Hi @pranathi. Of course, you can do it in Bash Script.  Please check my update.

Comment: Hi @pranathi. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could help.

Comment: Thanks Kevin,  but i cannot use PAT in my organization, could you provide me same with system access token with bash script.

Comment: @pranathi. Please refer to my update2. Feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @pranathi. Please refer to my update3. The easier method is using logging command. You can try it too.

Comment: Thank Kevin for your kind support

Comment: @pranathi. It's my pleasure. If the answer could solve your issue, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: i added script:  echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)" but it does not show any tags. added screenshot to question. may i know if i missing something

Comment: You need to check if the bash script has executed. And you could the task log: Build '3613' has following tags now: testtag. Please check if you could see the message

Comment: thanks.   actually echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)" command works. it sets tag but only issue is when i click on tags to list pipeline runs . it simply says no tags available. not sure any other modification needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest Api to update tags: [Tags - Add Build Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/add%20build%20tag?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Yaml example with the powershell task:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

steps:  
 - task: PowerShell@2
   env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       $user = ""
       $token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

       $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

       $org = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
       $teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"
       $buildId = "$(Build.BuildId)"
       $tagName = "test_tag"

       $restApiUpdateBuild = "$org/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/tags/$tagName`?api-version=6.0"

       function InvokePutReques ($PutUrl)
       {   
           return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PutUrl -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
       }

       $result = InvokePutReques $restApiUpdateBuild
     pwsh: true
```

Comment: is it possible to set with predefine variabels ,  i would like to change description of the pipeline or tag release with pipeline resources information

Comment: @pranathi, if you want to use `$(apiname)` as a tag, update `$tagName = "test_tag"` to `$tagName = "$(apiname)"` in the scripts

Comment: can i get samething in bash script as i have issue in running powershell script on our agents  ?

Answer (score 0):

The last instruction in your scripts `- script: git tag $(apiname)` may not work because you create tag on the build agent repository. You have to publish your tag.

Check this document to [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Publish tags to a remote repo: [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)

Comment: is it possible to tag with apiname variable  in above pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have to convert anything to base64 for auth info, and this worked:

```
  - powershell: |
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{YOUR_ORG_HARDOCDED_IF_YOU_WANT}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/tags/${{tag_name}}?api-version=6.0"
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Put
```