# I can't install a role from github by the version tag

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

The repo and tag look good to me. I can install it without specifying the tag, but then it's not versioned:

```
Starting galaxy role install process
[WARNING]: - ansible-role-shell was NOT installed successfully: - command /usr/bin/git checkout v0.0.1 failed in directory
/home/spiderman/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-96104higi5m4h/tmpzuylb5_v/ansible-role-shell (rc=1) - error: pathspec 'v0.0.1' did not match
any file(s) known to git
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
spiderman@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/natemarks/ansible-role-shell.git
Starting galaxy role install process
- extracting ansible-role-shell to /home/spiderman/.ansible/roles/ansible-role-shell
- ansible-role-shell was installed successfully
spiderman@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ ansible-galaxy list
# /home/spiderman/.ansible/roles
- ansible-role-shell, (unknown version)
[WARNING]: - the configured path /usr/share/ansible/roles does not exist.
[WARNING]: - the configured path /etc/ansible/roles does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: [_When the Galaxy server imports a role, it imports any git tags matching the Semantic Version format as versions. In turn, you can download a specific version of a role by specifying one of the imported tags._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-a-specific-version-of-a-role) but your repo doesn't provide any tags: https://github.com/natemarks/ansible-role-shell/tags

Comment: (Don't forget that a regular `git push` does not push tags https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195859/2123530)

Comment: om my!  it was exactly that. i had it tagged, but I didn't push tags.   so silly, but tyvm!!

Comment: If you post the comment as an answer, I can accept it . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had pushed tags. Answer in comments correctly pointed out that I did not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).