# I need help to put and share a code on gitlab

Tags: javascript, gitlab, git-bash, robocode

Hello i made a project wit my gr

```js
package CTJ;
import robocode.*;
/**/
public class Firsty extends Robot         <!--part 1-->

{
    public static final int MAX_HITS = 3;
    public static final int TIMER = 3;
    double lastBearing = 0;
    int hitCounter = 0;
    int myTimer = TIMER;
    

    public void run() {
        
        while(true) {

            myTimer = myTimer - 1;
            ahead(lastBearing);
            turnGunRight(360);
            back(100);
            turnGunRight(lastBearing + 90);
            
                if(myTimer == 0) {
                    
                    if(hitCounter > MAX_HITS) {
                        runLikeHell();
                    } else {
                        hitCounter = 0;
                        myTimer = TIMER;
                    } 
                }
        }
    }


    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {         <!--PART 2-->

        fire(10);
        back(5);
    }


    public void onHitByBullet(HitByBulletEvent e) {
        turnLeft(90 - e.getBearing());
        lastBearing = e.getBearing();
        hitCounter = hitCounter + 1;
    }
    
    public void onHitWall(HitWallEvent e) { <!--PART 3-->
        turnRight(e.getBearing() + 153);
    }
    
    public void runLikeHell() {
        out.println("evading....");
        turnLeft(172);
        ahead(500);
        hitCounter = 0;
        myTimer = TIMER;
    }   
}
```

n the gitlab. i already create the project and i alredy invite them but i dont know how to put the code in, i have the file on my desktop, but i dont know how to use gitlab i dont know the basic stuffs about it i have the gitbash on my computer i use windows can someone help me with it. if possible use screenshot so i can se step by step

This is my code

Comment: Follow this step by step tutorial on how to push any existing code to gitlab. https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-push-to-gitlab/

Comment: You should read the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)