# Detecting current commit's tag in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I committed some changes, then I tagged them:

```
git tag -f 0.9.5.0
```

Then I `git push` and a workflow starts. I need to obtain and check this tag in the workflow, and I can't find a way to do that.
`echo $GITHUB_REF` prints this:

> refs/heads/master

And `echo "github.ref_name=${{github.ref_name}}"` prints this:

> echo "github.ref_name=master"

So neither method detects the tag. Why is it, and how can I get my `0.9.5.0` tag?

Comment: You haven't pushed your tag tho. You're looking at runs for your push on master, but only tag-triggered pushes have their tag name in `github.ref_name`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: no, this answer doesn't explain why the tag is not visible to the runner. Are you saying this is how `git` works? Tags are not visible on the branch where the tagged commit is? What do you mean I haven't pushed my tag, how do I push it then?

Comment: It definitely does answer that question. Read again: you haven't pushed the 0.9.5.0 tag to your [file-commander repository](https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/file-commander/tags), you have just pushed your master branch. The `github.ref_name` will only be set to the tag name for a tag push; for a push on a branch it will contain the branch name. See [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git) for that.

Comment: @CodeCaster: thank you, this does answer my question, could you post an answer? P. S. `git` is super weird, I don't get how this was deemed the desired or even acceptable behavior.